# Passing different languages to PHP listener script

Tags: php, apache, api

I'm starting to make a simple API for my software.
I want it to be available in cURL, Ruby, Python, PHP, Java and Node.

It will pass only a few strings to a global PHP script, let's say https://api.domain.com (installed on Apache2).
Is it possible? Can the PHP receive information from other languages?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

HTTP is HTTP. The programming languages used to write the client, the server and any programs that the server accesses have no bearing on their ability to communicate with each other through the standard protocol.